# Using https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id= for the follow button remove button styling

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been following the web intents documentation on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#follow-intent which describes that the links need to be as follows:

```
intent/user?screen_name=xxx
```

but preferably

```
intent/user?user_id=xxx
```

Using the first example displays the styled twitter button, but using user_id does not.

Using screen_name

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=twitterapi" 
class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">
Follow@twitterapi</a>
```

Using user_id

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=6253282" 
class="twitter-follow-    button" data-show-count="false" 
data-size="large">Follow @twitterapi</a>
```

Is there a way to style the button if using user_id instead of screen_name

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set the use the .split() method on the href value splitting by "?" , or split("?").

Then write if and else if statements. One for starting with screen name and one for user name, then you can apply styles using jQuery's .attr() to apply the class you want as defined in you stylesheet.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: So are you saying to use the screen_name method, and then wait for twitter to perform its DOM manipulation. Then adjust the link to point to the user_id method?